# Ionic 4: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StateObservable: (?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I'm trying to run a particular spec file i am facing issue give as given below

[image]

I'm new to Unit Testing I'm not sure Why i'm getting this issue. any suggestion will help me to solve this issue

Comment: Can you provide the code of your component please. And eventually the service if it use them.